# Which Star Trek: TNG episodes show the Transporter controls in use?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I have an image in my head of O'Brien operating the transporter, sliding a finger or two up a marked panel towards a round area while saying "Energize".

Which TNG Episode is this from? I know there were several TOS episodes which showed physical levers being slid upward to 'energize' the transporter, but is there on on-screen reference for this action in TNG?

Comment: Short answer, loads. There's quite a nice view in [DS9: Emissary](https://youtu.be/Oxh-qoLz_pM?t=177)

Comment: never thought about excessive manual controls, sliding switches -- could doing it wrong affect the process so that the human is incompletely transported??

Comment: @releseabe  - I assume if your sleeve gets caught, your transportee dies.

Comment: yeah, probably happened all the time. or if they are too fast on the slider, the transportee loses some grey matter or they're an inch or two shorter. but the Galileo looked so cramped. (This is but another example of Star Trek inventing reasons for humans being in space.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Focusing purely on instances where we see the transporter *slider controls* being actuated, the first time we see them used on screen is **Season 1, Episode 21, *The Arsenal of Freedom***. The three stripes are present, but button presses at the bottom of the stripes are sufficient to cause (two of them) to light up. They then remain lit for the entire transport cycle.

[image]

**Season 1 Episode 24, *We'll Always Have Paris*.**
We hear three button presses and then we see the 'sliders' blinking. The third one remains lit throughout the cycle.

[image]

From the same episode. This time the slider remains intermittently lit.

[image]

**Season 2, Episode 2, *Where Silence Has Lease*** finds us with O'Brien in the transporter room [where he will remain for most of the series](https://chiefobrienatwork.com/post/106847752496/episode-20-training-day-read-the-next-episode). The sliders are now slid, but not individually.

[image]

**Season 2, Episode 5, *Loud as a Whisper*** finally gets us a couple of good solid O'Brien signature transporter 'slides to energise'.

[image]

[image]

**Season 2, Episode 7, *Unnatural Selection*** has this hand gesture repeated by one of O'Brien's flunkies with what can only be described as *greater flamboyance*.

[image]

**Season 2, Episode 12, *The Royale*** has a couple of scenes where O'Brien uses the sliders. For some reason they also randomly light up while he's doing other things with the controls. This time he uses the far left and middle sliders, ignoring the one on the right.

[image]

The second time, all *three* sliders light up, despite his hand only contacting the centre one.

[image]

**Season 2, Episode 17, *Samaritan Snare*** is odd because the middle and right sliders light up, *and then* the transporter crewman slides her hands up them, not the other way around.

[image]

**Season 2, Episode 20, *The Emissary*** has O'Brien back at his station. This time he operates the middle slider only.

[image]

**Season 3, Episode 3, *The Survivors*** has a nice view of the transporter used to transport 5 officers. The sliders are all slid upwards and fade on their own as the cycle completes.

[image]

**Season 3, Episode 14, *A Matter of Perspective*** has O'Brien using them in an emergency. We can't see which ones light up, but he's doing the 'slide' again. It appears that this is the *second* time he's operated them during this transport (the first time being ineffective).

[image]

**Season 3, Episode 23, *Sarek*** finds O'Brien heading off in a new direction, *slide up then down again* with all three sliders.

[image]

**Season 3, Episode 26, *The Best of Both Worlds, Part I*** has a brief side-on view of the sliders.

[image]

Later in the same episode, we see the three sliders but they don't actually slide, just grow progressively brighter.

[image]

**Season 4, Episode 1, *The Best of Both Worlds, Part II*** has the same *up and down* light effect as TNG: Sarek, again with three slides.

[image]

**Season 4, Episode 2, *Family*** sees O'Brien with the up-and-down-slide-motion. All three lights are now synced to his hand movements.

[image]

**Season 4, Episode 6, *Legacy*** is interesting because it has a nice close-up on the sliders.

[image]

**Season 4, Episode 8, *Future Imperfect*** has another ND chief using the up-and-down-slide-motion with all three lights. For the record this is a simulation rather than reality.

[image]

**Season 5, Episode 24, *The Next Phase*** has Transporter Chief Brossmer at the controls. The 'slide' starts normally with all three sliders but as the transport goes pear-shaped, they de-illuminate (in sequence) and then flash randomly up and down while she presses other buttons.

[image]

**Season 6, Episode 18, *Starship Mine*** has Picard operating the transporters in automatic mode. The sliders (all three) are slid up and then hold themselves at the top before shutting down prematurely.

[image]

**Season 7, Episode 22, *Bloodlines*** has La Forge using the transporters to intercept an attempt to beam a passenger off of the ship. All three slider are slid upward.

[image]

And in the same episode, Data operates all three sliders in the classic up-and-down-slide-motion.

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: Given you are still working on this epic task - may I suggest you add one of Scotty in TOS using the physical sliders for contrast.  (There may be alternate versions in the Cage or Where No Man has Gone before due to the set differences.)  But mostly I suggest it in the sense that to the viewer in 2020 a touch screen is not futuristic.  In 1989 this was quite a leap over TOS and demonstrated TNG was indeed in the future of TOS.

Comment: One of the most comprehensive answers I've seen - even by your standards. I'm sorely tempted to put a reward existing answer bounty on this but it's not like you need more rep :)

Comment: @JonClements - I'd have been done sooner if I hadn't kept stopping to watch entire episodes

Comment: +1 Wow, how did you capture all of these takes of the transporter controls? And in a single day!

Comment: Transporter operators must train long and hard to get the swipe right - one slip of the finger could result in terrible deformities. If I were the transporter operator's commanding officer, I'd think carefully before giving him or her a poor performance evaluation. Eventually everyone has to use the transporter . . .

Comment: Holy crap, man.  This is exactly what I was looking for!  I was hoping to make a nice gif of one of the better scenes, and here you've gone and identified TONS of them, and either found or made gifs of them already.  If any answer ever deserved the check, it's this one.

Comment: @RobertF - I (ahem) acquired the entire series and then watched them all at hyper-speed, stopping wherever I saw the transporter room. I then used a tool called [LICEcap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/) to screen-capture the video into handy gifs. I'm using photoshop CS5 to edit them down to size where needed.

Comment: There were surprisingly few views of the transporter controls in season 5, 6 and 7.

Comment: I'm still amazed how the control panels in ST:TNG still look slick and "futuristic" after ~30 years.

Comment: @RobertF - What astounds me is how good they look in comparison to the controls on shows like Discovery that just look like generic CGI rubbish; https://i.redd.it/j9ucqtuvwunz.jpg

Comment: @Valorum:   My only question is WHHHHYYYYY!    Somehow this lockdown thing means you apparently have even more time than usual.