# Are transporters meant to be used single handedly?

Tags: star-trek

If I recall correctly there seem to have been a number of occasions where people have been able to initiate a ship's transporter themselves and then get on the pad quickly enough to safely transport away.

Is the small delay which gives them enough time inherent to the transporter, or can they control this setting?

It usually seems that the transporter, when operated normally, starts to transport as soon as the operator engages it.

Comment: In TNG: Starship Mine, Picard has to press [a bunch of buttons before running onto the platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rNcX.gif). I'm guessing the transport normally starts as soon as you've slid the sliders otherwise.

Comment: @Valorum seems possible, though I imagine you also have to specify coordinates somehow. BTW, amazed at how fast you found that gif!

Comment: I took it from another answer I posted; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/230503/20774

Comment: I think it's much more like operating on yourself. [Theoretically possible](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-32481442), but not the sort of thing you'd want to do in anything other than an emergency

Comment: From the TNG era onwards the computer might not actually start the beaming sequence until it detects one or more people have stepped up onto the transporter pad

Comment: @Valorum wow! That story reminds me of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMDdjhWe9NQ a bit too

Answer (score 2):

One would presume that you could use it either way, press a button to transport immediately, or set a few seconds delay.

Any modern camera will have a similar function. It can take a photo as soon as you press the button, or you can set a delay timer, so that you can photograph yourself.  Why wouldn't a 23rd century device have a similar function?

Comment: It is also worth noticing that you don't need to be on transporter pad for transporter to lock into you and teleport you.